# Does $stable in SystemVerilog Operate on Buses?

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

I would like to verify that a bus is stable in an assertion. For example, I would expect the following assertion to flag an error if `data` changes in the clock after the `re` falling edge.

```
wire clk, rst_n, re;
wire [15:0] data;

a_chk_stable_data:
  assert property (@(posedge clk) disable iff(!rst_n)
    ($fell(re) |=> $stable(data[15:0])))
  else begin
    $display("ERROR: one or more bits of data not stable");
  end
```

I believe that `$rose` only operates on the LSB of a bus ([link](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/assertions7.html)). Does `$stable` only operate on the LSB as well, or does it support signals of any width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the spec](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), `$stable` operates on the entire expression.  Whereas `$rose` and `$fell` operate on the LSB of the expression.

From section 16.9.3 of [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf):

> — `$rose` returns true if the LSB of the expression changed to 1 . Otherwise, it returns false.
>   — `$fell` returns true if the LSB of the expression changed to 0 . Otherwise, it returns false.
>   — `$stable` returns true if the value of the expression did not change. Otherwise, it returns false.
>   — `$changed` returns true if the value of the expression changed. Otherwise, it returns false.